# Layout to center not coming up in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Hi I am trying to set a layout and I have three images in it. I am trying to center the three images with couple of paddings so that it is centered in all screens and resolution. Strangely they get centered in my phone (Nexus 5) and on Samsung devices they are not centered. I am not sure how to fix this?

Please check the screen shot from Samsung.

[image]

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutrelative"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/blue" >



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mainImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingRight="45dp"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/action_home" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/favimage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mainImage"
        android:paddingRight="45dp"
        android:paddingLeft="45dp"
        android:src="@drawable/favimage" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/eyeImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/favimage"
        android:paddingLeft="45dp"
        android:src="@drawable/eyeimage" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong? Let me know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just Add `android:gravity="center"` in your root layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutrelative"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/blue" >



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mainImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingRight="45dp"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/action_home" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/favimage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mainImage"
        android:paddingRight="45dp"
        android:paddingLeft="45dp"
        android:src="@drawable/favimage" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/eyeImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/favimage"
        android:paddingLeft="45dp"
        android:src="@drawable/eyeimage" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `android:gravity="center"` is used in LinearLayout, for relative layout it's     `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @DhavalPatel `android:layout_gravity="center"` also working with `RelativeLayout` Currently I create one demo for this and `android:layout_gravity="center"` completely work with `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score 1):

Add `android:gravity="center"` in your Root layout .

- `android:gravity` sets the gravity of the content of the View it's
  used on.
- `android:layout_gravity` sets the gravity of the View or
  Layout *relative to its parent*.

Finally

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/layoutrelative"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
   android:background="@color/blue"
   android:gravity="center">
```

Answer (score 0):

add `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` to your child items

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `LinearLayout` here, Using `RelativeLayout` and setting fix padding will not make it responsive for all screen. You can check the design preview in android studio even before installing in real device for multiple screen.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutrelative"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mainImage"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/action_home" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/favimage"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/favimage" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/eyeImage"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/eyeimage" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use need to use `LinearLayout` for this. The below code will work for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layoutrelative"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/blue" > 

<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/mainImage"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingRight="45dp"
    android:paddingLeft="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/action_home" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/favimage"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mainImage"
    android:paddingRight="45dp"
    android:paddingLeft="45dp"
    android:src="@drawable/favimage" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/eyeImage"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/favimage"
    android:paddingLeft="45dp"
    android:src="@drawable/eyeimage" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This will divide the whole screen width equally. If you just need the same layout to be centred the use `android:gravity="center"` in your parent `RelativeLayout.`

Answer (score 0):

add `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` to first ImageView
`android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` to second ImageView
`android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` to third ImageView